# C++: malloc : error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘uint8_t*’

Tags: c++

I got this problem:

> invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘uint8_t*’

When doing this:

```
int             numBytes;
uint8_t         *buffer;

buffer=malloc(numBytes); //error here, why?
```

or must I have to put it like this?

```
buffer=malloc(numBytes);
```

Please explain this.

Comment: Do use a smart pointer of some sort.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot implicitly cast from `void *` in C++ (unlike C in this respect).  You could do:

```
buffer = static_cast<uint8_t *>(malloc(numBytes));
```

but really, you should just be using `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`!

Comment: You can `static_cast` from `void*`, and probably should if only because a `reinterpret_cast` will cause people to panic unnecessarily.

Comment: This is not a situation for reinterpret_cast<> which you should reserve for very specific situations where you actually want people to re-check the code (especially when porting).

Comment: @SteveJessop What should you do if you're calling external C code in another file which uses malloc() but the C++ compiler complains about the non-existent cast. Do you have to manually add casts to the C code so you can use it in C++ code?

Comment: @Nubcake: compile your C code with a C compiler, and compile your C++ code with a C++ compiler, then call the C code from the C++ code using an `extern "C"` declaration in a header file. The C++ compiler should never see the call to `malloc` if it's in C code. If you want to convert C code to C++, so that you can compile it with a C++ compiler, while continuing to use `malloc` then yes, you'll need to add a cast to it as part of that process. Do this at the same time as renaming any C variables named `class`, and any other changes needed to make it valid C++ with the desired meaning!

Comment: @SteveJessop Ah yes, I managed to figure out that I had to compile the C code first then link it with the C++ code and do you as described. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In C++ it is not allowed to simply assign a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type (as always there are exception to the rule. It is for example valid to assign a any pointer to a void pointer.)

What you should do is to cast your void pointer to a uint8_t pointer:

```
buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc (numBytes);
```

Note: This is only necessary in C++, in C it was allowed to mix and match pointers. Most C compilers give a warning, but it is valid code.

Since you're using C++ you could also use new and delete like this:

```
buffer = new uint8_t[numBytes];
```

and get rid of your buffer using:

```
delete[] buffer;
```

In general you shouldn't use malloc and free unless you have to interface with c libraries.

Comment: "In general you shouldn't use malloc and free unless you have to". Shouldn't use new[] and delete[] unless you have to either. `vector` does fine almost all the time.

Comment: And you shouldn't use c style casts in c++ either.

Answer (score 2):

Malloc returns a void pointer; when you use it, you have to cast the return value to a pointer to whatever datatype you're storing in it.

```
buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(numBytes);
```

Comment: Only in C++. And if you're in C++ you shouldn't be using C style casts or malloc anyway.