# Error when compiling cpp file

Tags: c++, c, pointers, sdl, codeblocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: malloc : error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘uint8_t*’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010917/c-malloc-error-invalid-conversion-from-void-to-uint8-t)

Hello,

I have this little function

```
Uint32 moveSprite(Uint32 interval, void *param)
{
    SDL_Rect* spritePos = param; 
    spritePos->x++;

    return interval;
}
```

The problem here is quite simple, I'm using codeblocks, when i save this file as a C file, it compiles with no problems, but once I save it as a C++ file, I have this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'SDL_Rect*'|
```

Does anyone have a clue on what's the problem here?

Comment: Writing multi-language source files is bad for the brain. Do it at your own risk :)

Comment: @pmg: do you know ObjectiveC++? :)

Comment: @jv42: lol, no. Mixing `C` and `preprocessor` "language" is more than enough for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is valid C, not valid C++. You need to add an explicit casting for it to compile

Either C-style:

```
SDL_Rect* spritePos = (SDL_Rect *)param;
```

Or more C++-ish:

```
SDL_Rect* spritePos = static_cast<SDL_Rect *>(param);
```

A better solution would be to change the parameter type instead if that's possible for you. Avoid `void *` whenever you can!

Comment: @Bo Persson: thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast the typeless pointer to a type. For example:

```
SDL_Rect* spritePos = static_cast<SDL_Rect*>(param);
```

Read up on casting in C++.